# Allowing VNC connections into Linux Mint

Tags: linux, vnc, linux-mint, packages, remote-connection

Do any programs need to be installed that aren't included in the default install of Linux Mint in order for it to allow VNC connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is go to menu->control center->remote desktop. Then click on allow others to view your desktop. It will also show the ip that people need to enter to connect.

Comment: I don't see that in my control center. Maybe they've renamed it in Linux Mint 14, or maybe I'm missing some packages?

Answer (score 1):

The "remote desktop" option no longer seems to be available in Mint > 12.

This worked for me in Mint 14 MATE, taken from: http://apipeandakeyboard.com/2012/05/28/using-remote-desktop-in-mint-13-maya/

The VNC server included in the distro is called "Vino", but it doesn't seem to startup by default or have any menu item.

**Enable Vino**

- From the terminal, run: vino-preferences
- Place ticks in both: Sharing --> Allow other users to view and control your desktop
- Set a password and other options

**Create a menu item for Vino**

- Right-click the "Menu" option on the taskbar
- Select "Edit Menu"
- Select "New Item"
- Set "Command" to: `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable`

**Launch Vino on startup**

- Select "Menu" -> "Control Center"
- Select "Startup Applications"
- Drag and drop the Vino menu item to the preferences window

**Other stuff**

- To find the IP address to use when connecting from other machines, run "ifconfig" from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need a VNC server. I don't know if Mint includes one by default, but popular choices are Vino and RealVNC (Xvnc).

Answer (score 0):

I have a headless Linux Mint server that uses vino for VNC access.  I configured it to  autologin, and then I access the server with VNC whenever I need it.  It works great.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Mint 14 the menu option is called Desktop Sharing (just press the windows-button and typ "desktop sharing").

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still encountering issues with VNC connections into a Mint installation, see here:

https://mintguide.org/tools/140-remote-desktop-via-vnc-from-windows-to-linux-mint.html

This is the only guide I have found that actually works.